# Common Custom Control using win32 api

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been searching the net for different things about the win32 API, but it seems all information on it is rather sparse.

I am looking to create a simple window that show rss feed and i want to make independent of technology like MFC, Windows form and WPF so i need it in win32 so i will show it in any application. guide me how its possible.

Comment: Sparse? Which net have you been looking on?

Comment: sorry for very novice question i am quite new to all this. @JonathanPotter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your own window class.
Register it.
Create the window.

It should handle:

- Implement WM_PAINT and draw your stuff.
- For further functions you need to handle mouse input. (WM_MOUSE... messages)
- Also you need to handle keyboard Input (WM_KEYDOWN messages)
- Next would be to implement scrolling (may be you need to design this before you start with drawing).

You can't show such a window if you have a DirectX game or Windodows App, when using the Win32 approach... showing it in *every* application is nearly impossible. Also I am not sure what you mean with *every* application. At least you can use it in every Win32 desktop application.

All this basics are handled in Windows tutorials and books like "Programming Windows" from Charles Petzold.

Also the MSDN shows you all basis messages you need to handle.

This is covered also bei articles like this one:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559385/Custom-Controls-in-Win-API-The-Basics

Searching for "custom windows control win32 api" would lead you directly to concrete code and tutorials.

Comment: thanks its help me. sorry for very novice question i am quite new to all this.